# jQuery selector for a class followed by a space and then again another class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="classA classB">the content</div>
```

What I would like is a selector that selects all of the divs that start with classA and I did this:

```
$("div[class^='classA'");
```

but since I (for example) have also classes like:

```
<div class="classAsuffix">
```

that selector would grab this div also, and I do not want that.

So, I want a selector that will get me all of the divs that do start with classA but then after that have a space so in general: give me all divs which have "classA (space) someOtherClass".

I hope I'm clear with my request. Thank you for your help!

Oh, forgot tot mention: I tried this:

```
$("div[class^='classA ']") but it doesn't work...
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the standard "has class" selector, `$("div.classA")`?

Comment: What if classA is elsewhere in the attribute? Do you want to exclude that?

Comment: @Chowlett: That would select elements with only that class as well.

Comment: @Chowlett: yes, actually goes in the each() function so I need to go through all the div which have classA _space_ someOtherClass

Comment: Ok. What _exactly_ do you want to select? All divs with `classA` and... any other class? Just `classB`? Does it matter where in the class list `classA` appears (which would be a bit of an odd thing to do, but hey)

Comment: @Nikola: As far as I can tell, your last one should be working, at least with the jQuery 1.6.1 and jQuery 1.5.2; see my answer for details, but I've tried a *lot* of browsers and they're all working as I believe you've said you wanted...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: yes, apparently this was due to the jQuery version (had 1.3.2 - ah, don't ask why...) Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>The quotes around your value should be double quotes, not single quotes.</s> *Actually, it doesn't seem to matter.* So:

```
var matches = $('div[class^="classA "]');
```

...which [works with the latest jQuery](http://jsbin.com/iruza4/2). It matches an element with a `class` attribute *starting with* `"classA "` and so doesn't match `div class="classA"` but does match `div class="classA classB"`. But your version with single quotes [works too](http://jsbin.com/iruza4/3). I've tried Chrome 11 (Linux & Windows), Firefox 3.6 (Linux), Firefox 4.0.1 (Windows), IE6, IE7, IE9, Opera 11 (Linux & Windows), and Safari 5 (Windows). I've tried jQuery 1.6.1 (the links above are to the "latest"), and [jQuery 1.5.2](http://jsbin.com/iruza4/4). All gave the same result, finding only what I understand you want it to find.

But — and this is slightly off-topic — I'd take a step back and look hard at why this need is coming up. It's very unusual, which suggests there may be a better approach... Without knowing the underlying need, though, I could be wrong there.

Comment: Never knew jQuery/Sizzle didn't accept single quotes for attributes (although admittedly I did suspect they were the problem)...

Comment: @BoltClock: That was my impression from the docs, but it appears to be a mistaken impression; see update above.

Answer (score 0):

you could combine two statements.

```
$("div[class^='classA'].classA");
```

This case you would check for class beginning with `classA` and also that the element has this class. But this would also be valid `class="classASuffix classA classB"` or `class="classA"`.

Comment: Would also select elements with only that class.

Answer (score 0):

This should get all DIVs with `class="classA classB"`:

`$("div[class^='classA'][class$='classB']");`

Selects all DIVs where the class-attribute STARTS WITH 'classA' and ENDS WITH 'classB'

http://jsfiddle.net/9dQ9Z/

Answer (score 0):

you can use $('div[class~="classA"]');
See the following link for explanation:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This would select all divs that have both classA and classB, but not divs with just classAsuffix and classB:

$('div.classA.classB');